# eclipse luna external jar classpath broken

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

In Luna when I click on build path, click libraries, add external jar files, it will not show the file dialog. Sometimes if I restart eclipse it will work but only for the first few items I add, then it stops allowing the dialog to appear.
It's very strange and no errors or anything else appears. I tried Lunda 4.4.0 IDE Java version and also the EE version same thing both 64 bit versions.

Any idea what could be causing this?